# Relation between limit of functions and sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that the sequence
$$ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}$$
diverges. I know that
$$\lim \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} = \infty$$.
Is there any theorem that relations the limit of the function with the limit of the sequence when we are talking about limits that does not exists (as real number)? I know there is one theorem that relations the limits when it exists, but I dont know about this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you know what you claim to know? You can use the same proof.

Comment: Using L'Hospital

Comment: Aah. Then can you flesh out what it means for $\frac{\sqrt x}{\log x}$ to converge to $+\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Just inspect the definition of $\lim \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} = \infty$. It says given any $M \gt 0$ there is a $m \gt 0$ such that $ x \ge m \implies \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x} \gt M$. Notice the definition for an infinite limit of a sequence is similar. Let $M \gt 0$ be arbitrary. Then there is a natural number $n' \gt m$. Then for every $n \gt n' \gt m$ we have that $ \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n} \gt M $. No way can the sequence converge.

Comment: Suppose a case that the limit of the function does not exists, for example, $\lim_{x \to \infty} sin(x)$. Can we apply something like this for this case?

Comment: Note the limit must be taken when $x \to \infty$. Let $l \in \Bbb R$ be arbitrary. Then since the limit of the function is not $l$, there is a positive quantity $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that given any $x $ there is an $x' \in \Bbb R$ such that $x' \gt x$ and $ |f(x)-l| \ge \epsilon $. Again use a similar argument saying there is no $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $n \ge m \implies |f(n) - l| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: Might seem complicated. All you need to do is this. When we take a limit as $x \to \infty$ what we do is to say the function is as close as you like (distance is less than $\epsilon$) to the limit for every $x \gt m$. The existence of such an $m$ for each $\epsilon $ is the condition for the limit. Note that since this holds for all real numbers greater than $m$ it also holds for natural numbers greater than $m$. Now **this** is nothing but an analogous definition.

Comment: f must be a continuous function? Because if we define f(x)=1  for all x natural and f(x)=x elsewhere, then the limit of f does not exists but the limit of f(n) does.

Comment: True but then the infinite limit of $f(x)$ does not exist. If you *know* that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ then you can infer that $ f(n) \to l $. A continuity assumption is not needed. Again simply look at the definitions